# Why Keras and SKLearn give me different accuracy values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have created a linear classification model. It takes images as input and classifies them with one of two classes. I want to test the accuracy of my model with a different dataset than the one used for training.

These are the parameters I have used to compile the model:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

After training, I load a different dataset for the "production" tests.

```py
dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
      '/content/test-dataset-2',
      image_size=(512, 384),
      labels='inferred',
      label_mode='categorical',
).map(preprocess)
```

I calculate the accuracy of the model against the given dataset using the `evaluate` method:

```
model.evaluate(dataset)
```

It outputs an accuracy of 73,33% and loss of ~56.

However, if I calculate the accuracy through a different method, I get a different result. For example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay, classification_report

def get_labels(arr):
  return np.argmax(arr, axis=1)

# I am probably doing too much hard work over here...
predictions = to_categorical(np.argmax(model.predict(dataset), axis=1), 2)
y = np.concatenate([y for x, y in dataset], axis=0)

cm = confusion_matrix(get_labels(y), get_labels(predictions))
cm_display = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm).plot()
```

This outputs the following Confusion Matrix:

[image]

Which amounts for 47,33% accuracy, a drastically different result than the one given by `model.evaluate`.

So, which one is wrong, and why?

On one hand, I'm prone to believe the accuracy given by `model.evaluate` is too high, I don't think the model is that good.

On the other hand, it's likely that I have made some mistake in the code that one hot encodes the predictions before passing them to the confusion matrix function.

Comment: `evaluate()` returns a value for loss and whatever your defined metric is, but you never show what metric you used.

Comment: Can you share what loss you used to compile your model?

Comment: I have edited my post with the `model.compile` call and it's parameters. I used categorical cross entropy for the loss function, and accuracy as the metric

Comment: Set `shuffle=False` in `image_dataset_from_directory`.